# Worth using parallel instead of forking processes in a for loop?

Tags: background-process, gnu-parallel

The following for loop runs thousands of jobs in parallel

```
OSMSOURCE=europe-latest.o5m
for SHAPEFILE in URBAN_[A-Z]*[0-9] ;do
    cd $SHAPEFILE
    for POLYGON in *.poly ;do
        osmconvert --drop-version $OSMSOURCE -B=$POLYGON --out-o5m > $(basename $OSMSOURCE .o5m |tr "-" "_")_$(basename $POLYGON .poly).o5m &
    done
    cd ..
done
```

I want to learn how GNU parallel performs and understand if it is worth using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, GNU parallel will do the same and it's quite as easy to use. Its advantage is that it will take care of the number of CPU cores on your machine and by default it will not execute more jobs than that (*).

Your program doesn't. If you have hundreds of `.poly` files, you will spawn hundreds of `osmconvert` jobs, which at best may not be optimum, and at worst may put your system down (it depends on your resources).

Your program would be something like (not tested):

```
OSMSOURCE=europe-latest.o5m
OSMBASENAME="$(echo "${OSMSOURCE%.o5m}" | tr - _)"

for SHAPEFILE in URBAN_[A-Z]*[0-9]; do
    cd "$SHAPEFILE"
    for POLYGON in *.poly; do
        echo "cd '$SHAPEFILE'; osmconvert --drop-version '$OSMSOURCE' -B='$POLYGON' --out-o5m > '${OSMBASENAME}_${POLYGON%.poly}.o5m'"
    done
    cd ..
done | parallel        # You may want to add a -j option
```

(*) You can give it your own threshold. You may want to keep a few spare CPU cores for something else. On the other hand, if I/Os are the bottleneck, you may want to give a higher number than the default one.

Comment: I only need to GNU-parallel the inner loop, right? Traversing through the directories (outer loop) is same/best kept in a for loop construct.

Comment: I'd would use parallel in the outer loop, and give a command to parallel that includes the directory change.

Comment: Hm... yes, confused I was. There are hundreds of directories. And then, some times, there are multiple .poly files inside a directory. Was busy with that last part now, hence the "only inner loop" thought.

Comment: This is actually your inner loop that must generate commands for `parallel` with `echo`/`printf`, but that command should begin with "cd  $SHAPEFILE; osmconvert ...` (thus, one `osmconvert` at a time) and parallel should be put in the outer loop so that several `URBAN_*` directories can be processed simultaneously.

Comment: I have added a code sample to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like:

```
OSMSOURCE=europe-latest.o5m
export OSMSOURCE

doit() {
  cd "$1"
  POLYGON="$2"
  osmconvert --drop-version $OSMSOURCE -B=$POLYGON --out-o5m > $(basename $OSMSOURCE .o5m |tr "-" "_")_$(basename $POLYGON .poly).o5m
}
export -f doit
```

You can now test that this works by hand:

```
doit URBAN_dir file_in_URBAN_dir.poly
```

When that works:

```
parallel doit {//} {/} ::: URBAN_[A-Z]*[0-9]/*.poly
```

If that gives `command too long`, try:

```
find URBAN_[A-Z]*[0-9] -name *.poly | parallel doit {//} {/}
```

Or:

```
find . | grep -E 'URBAN_[A-Z].*[0-9]/.*.poly$' | parallel doit {//} {/}
```

Spend an hour on walking through `man parallel_tutorial`. Your command line will thank you for it.

Comment: I was on the same path (after reading multiple similar examples). I did not want to cheat (by reading the proposed solutions here) but I consumed all options I can think of. I missed the `export -f` part!

Comment: Not exactly, after all. First, I want(ed) to run a shell script that does the inner loop and feed it, along with the pattern to match directories, to `parallel`.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect what it is you want. It is not clear from your comment here.

Comment: My comment might be unclear and unnecessary. The solution is just perfect to what I want. I'll try both answers, see what is best to accept.

Comment: I feel the single most important lesson from the above answer is the syntax "trick" `parallel command {//} {/}`. Thanks for that. I was struggling to find a way to feed correctly once the path(s) and then the filename(s).

Comment: I've accepted the answer of @xhienne because he did answer earlier. My preference, though, is [a for-loop with absolute path and file names, fed to parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390260/13011). Thank you for all of the details.

Answer (score 0):

Timing tests of the conversions based on the available answers and a small set of data.

## Test data set

Directories of ESRI Shapefiles

```
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT001L2
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT002L2
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT003L2
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT004L2
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT005L2
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT006L1
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_UK546L0
```

which include the following 9 [.poly](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Polygon_Filter_File_Format) files

```
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT001L2/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT001L2_0.poly
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT002L2/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT002L2_0.poly
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT003L2/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT003L2_0.poly
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT004L2/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT004L2_0.poly
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT005L2/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT005L2_0.poly
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT006L1/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_AT006L1_0.poly
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_UK546L0/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_UK546L0_0.poly
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_UK546L0/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_UK546L0_1.poly
URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_UK546L0/URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_UK546L0_2.poly
```

will launch 9 jobs in parallel

## Forking

```
for SHAPEFILE in URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_[A-Z]*[0-9]/ ;do cd $SHAPEFILE && for POLYGON in *.poly ;do time osmconvert --drop-version $OSMSOURCE -B=$POLYGON --out-o5m > $(basename $OSMSOURCE .o5m |tr "-" "_")_$(basename $POLYGON .poly).o5m & done && cd .. ;done
```

> ```
> real    6m0.951s
> user    5m36.869s
> sys     0m20.298s
>
> real    6m23.591s
> user    5m43.808s
> sys     0m20.336s
>
> real    6m24.066s
> user    5m44.619s
> sys     0m19.936s
>
> real    6m24.129s
> user    5m45.239s
> sys     0m19.378s
>
> real    6m29.208s
> user    5m43.094s
> sys     0m19.314s
>
> real    6m30.974s
> user    5m44.318s
> sys     0m19.870s
>
> real    6m33.625s
> user    5m45.233s
> sys     0m19.658s
>
> real    6m33.731s
> user    5m45.712s
> sys     0m20.001s
>
> real    6m41.014s
> user    6m15.112s
> sys     0m19.571s
> ```

## GNU Parallel

```
for SHAPEFILE in URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_[A-Z]*[0-9]*/ ;do cd "$SHAPEFILE"; for POLYGON in *.poly ;do echo "cd '$SHAPEFILE'; time osmconvert --drop-version '$OSMSOURCE' -B='$POLYGON' --out-o5m > $(basename $OSMSOURCE .o5m |tr "-" "_")_$(basename $POLYGON .poly).o5m"; done; cd ..; done |parallel -j 10
```

> ```
> real    6m19.005s
> user    5m42.739s
> sys     0m18.798s
>
> real    6m26.939s
> user    5m44.689s
> sys     0m19.257s
>
> real    6m27.152s
> user    5m44.597s
> sys     0m19.644s
>
> real    6m28.821s
> user    5m41.650s
> sys     0m18.283s
>
> real    6m38.174s
> user    5m44.367s
> sys     0m19.564s
>
> real    6m40.277s
> user    5m45.000s
> sys     0m19.650s
>
> real    6m39.940s
> user    5m45.421s
> sys     0m19.208s
>
> real    6m40.285s
> user    5m45.443s
> sys     0m19.393s
>
> real    6m40.428s
> user    5m48.828s
> sys     0m18.871s
> ```

### Using absolute path and file names

```
for SHAPEFILE in URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_[A-Z]*[0-9]*/ ;do for POLYGON in $SHAPEFILE*.poly ;do echo "time osmconvert --drop-version --out-o5m $OSMSOURCE -B=$(readlink -f $POLYGON) > $(dirname `readlink -f $POLYGON`)/$(basename ${OSMSOURCE%.o5m})_$(basename ${POLYGON%.poly}).o5m" ;done ;done |parallel -j 10
```

> ```
> real    6m6.919s
> user    5m39.203s
> sys     0m19.659s
>
> real    6m23.779s
> user    5m43.835s
> sys     0m19.225s
>
> real    6m26.033s
> user    5m45.370s
> sys     0m19.235s
>
> real    6m26.871s
> user    5m46.124s
> sys     0m19.780s
>
> real    6m33.355s
> user    5m41.902s
> sys     0m18.556s
>
> real    6m34.368s
> user    5m42.973s
> sys     0m19.156s
>
> real    6m37.063s
> user    5m46.169s
> sys     0m19.669s
>
> real    6m37.363s
> user    5m46.846s
> sys     0m19.194s
>
> real    6m37.428s
> user    5m49.679s
> sys     0m19.674s
> ```

### Defining a shell function

```
OSMSOURCE=$(realpath europe-latest.o5m)
export OSMSOURCE

osmpolyclip() {
    cd "$1"
    POLYGON="$2"
    osmconvert --drop-version $OSMSOURCE -B=$POLYGON --out-o5m > $(basename $OSMSOURCE .o5m |tr "-" "_")_$(basename $POLYGON .poly).o5m
}
```

and

```
parallel time osmpolyclip {//} {/} ::: URAU_[A-Z]*[0-9]/*.poly
```

> ```
> real    6m19.749s
> user    5m41.909s
> sys     0m19.162s
>
> real    6m23.559s
> user    5m43.881s
> sys     0m18.748s
>
> real    6m34.149s
> user    5m41.859s
> sys     0m18.895s
>
> real    6m38.776s
> user    5m44.614s
> sys     0m18.767s
>
> real    6m38.817s
> user    5m44.420s
> sys     0m19.038s
>
> real    6m39.421s
> user    5m46.060s
> sys     0m18.819s
>
> real    6m39.889s
> user    5m45.917s
> sys     0m19.541s
>
> real    6m39.956s
> user    5m48.368s
> sys     0m19.742s
>
> real    6m51.397s
> user    6m26.095s
> sys     0m19.306s
> ```

This is however a minimal test set, comparing to the thousands of Polygon files to be tasked for conversion. On top of that, the files reside in a remote directory which factually slows down reading and writing.

Comment: user+sys is fairly close to real, so you are limited by CPU - not by I/O. You do not write how many cores you use. Also the total time (of running all jobs) is interesting. I will expect GNU Parallel to outperform forking when the number of jobs is 10 * number_of_cores, and you should get even better performance if you do `-j+2` so you can have a couple of jobs waiting for I/O and still have 100% CPU utilization.

Comment: In the test above: 9 conversions, only 9 cores are used. "10 x numbers_of_cores" is, though, the case here. I expect, too, that GNU Parallel will perform better from what I have seen so far. I will post results once I get to run the conversions for the whole set of data (something 3500 .poly files). The system is a "server" graded one. It has 80 cores.

Comment: I added the timings for all conversions as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Timings in an 80-core system

Using absolute path and file names,

```
for SHAPEFILE in URAU_RG_100K_2011_2014_[A-Z]*[0-9]*/ ;do for POLYGON in $SHAPEFILE*.poly ;do echo "time osmconvert --drop-version --out-o5m $OSMSOURCE -B=$(readlink -f $POLYGON) > $(dirname `readlink -f $POLYGON`)/$(basename ${OSMSOURCE%.o5m})_$(basename ${POLYGON%.poly}).o5m" ;done ;done |parallel -j 10
```

the timings for 3559 conversions, in seconds, using GNU Parallel, are

```
 timings.real    timings.user    timings.sys

 Min.   :387.4   Min.   :367.5   Min.   :17.95
 1st Qu.:636.8   1st Qu.:616.3   1st Qu.:19.35
 Median :639.4   Median :618.5   Median :19.74
 Mean   :637.6   Mean   :616.8   Mean   :19.81
 3rd Qu.:642.5   3rd Qu.:621.5   3rd Qu.:20.15
 Max.   :709.3   Max.   :689.9   Max.   :27.34
```

### Details of the system

The processes were ran from inside a dockerised Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (see https://hub.docker.com/r/_/ubuntu/), while the host is a CentOS box (Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP).  The total memory is **1056760752 kB** and the number of *Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-4820 v3 @ 1.90GHz* processors are 80.